# Filter a Meteor Collection

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a mongoDB (meteor) collection that returns a collection of objects with the fetch method. Each return object in the array is of this form

```
  {quiz : {_id : 1,
           title : 'The days of our lives'}
   user : {name : 'Jamie'}
   score : 34}
```

I want to filter the query result and group by quiz title so that i can group all the scores according to the quiz title. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probably best way to do this is by utilising the quiz `_id`. You may get into a scenario where two titles are alike, but the quizzes aren't. Then your groups would get messy. So simply use the dot notation and find all answers applied to that quiz like so:

```
var answersByQuiz1 = Answers.find({
    'quiz._id': 1
}).fetch();
```

If you want several groups of answers, you can do:

```
var answers = Answers.find({
    'quiz._id': {
        $in: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] // ids of concern
    }
}).fetch();
```

And group them on client using for example `underscorejs`:

```
_.groupBy(answers, function(answer){ return answer.quiz._id; });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var filter = Collectionname.find({'quiz.title': 'The days of our lives'}).fetch();
console.log(filter);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!